# How to enable Full Text Search in SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, sql-server-express

When I downloaded SQL Server 2008 Express, I did not think I would need to use Full
Text Search.

Now I would like to use the AdventureWorks sample database but cannot install it without Full Text Search.

Is there a way to install this without reinstalling SQL Server 2008 Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download and run the advanced version of SQL2008 it will offer an option to add features. I would advice the version that includes the management studio as well.

Edit: 
The menu-sequence is:  Installation, New Sql-Server stand-alone or add features

Comment: but i already installed sql2008,,now where that option wl get

Answer (score 1):

A step-by-step instruction how to up grade SQL 2008 Express with additional features are found at the bottom of [this blog post](http://www.arguingwithmyself.com/archives/106-how-to-install-sql-server-2008-express-with-visual-web-developer-2008-express).